# Get Geopoints from parse.com javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, geopoints

I have succesfuly stored some geopoints in Parse.com and now in another page i want to console log them all so i can place them into some variables and then put one marker in google map.
So i'm trying with this code to get them but for sure i miss some thing and i need your advice.

```
    Parse.initialize("APPID", "JSKEY");
    var PhotoObject = Parse.Object.extend('magazia');
    var photoObject = new PhotoObject();
    var query = new Parse.Query(PhotoObject);
    query.select('latlon');
    query.find({
        success: function(locationList) {
            alert("Successfully retrieved " + locationList.length + " locations.");
            for (var i = 0; i < locationList.length; i++) {
                var locationsBlock = {};
                locationsBlock = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(locationList[i]));
                var location = {};
                location = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(locationsBlock.geolocation));
                alert(location.latitude);
            };
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
```

So i have a class called "magazia"
and inside that class there is a column which is called "latlon" and its a Geopoint. The content of this column is for example  `48.29124, 28.52015` float number.
The alert shows me the correct number of rows that there are in the "magazia" class.

Does anyone knows why i dont get the results from my code above?
thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you moving from the parse object into JSON text and then into a plain JS object? And then from that plain JS to JSON text and back to a plain JS object?

Comment: @Wain i wanted to post only the latitude for example and i was just trying some stuff... Not sure how to do it and parse.com documentation is not very helpfull about geopoints, you have any idea?

Comment: you just `get` the geopoint from the object and ask for the `laltitude` and `longitude`. are you saying the alert doesn't show the latitude?

Comment: @Wain nope, i only get the first alert, after it nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that was a stupid mistake

```
 var PhotoObject = Parse.Object.extend('magazia');
    var photoObject = new PhotoObject();
    var query = new Parse.Query(PhotoObject);
    query.select('latlon');
    query.find({
        success: function(locationList) {
            console.log("Successfully retrieved " + locationList.length + " locations.");
            for (var i = 0; i < locationList.length; i++) {
                var locationsBlock = {};
                locationsBlock = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(locationList[1]));
                var location = {};
                location = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(locationsBlock.latlon));

                var lat = location.latitude;
                var lon = location.longitude;
                console.log(lat, lon);
            };
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
```

instead of `locationsBlock.geolocation`
there should be  `locationsBlock.latlon`